# Trying to setup subdomain on Apache2 but getting subdomain is unavailable

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, virtual-machines

I am trying to setup a subdomain in Apache2, I have two folders in www folder, ankurkaushal & owncloud. I want to make subdomain for owncloud.

I have a dedicated IP address for my server and I have setup A records on registrar's end too.

Whenever I try access owncloud.ankurkaushal.me, I get that owncloud.ankurkaushal.me is unavailable.

Here's my sites-available/default file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ankurkaushal@outlook.com
    ServerAlias ankurkaushal.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ankurkaushal/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/ankurkaushal/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

#Owncloud

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ankurkaushal@outlook.com
    ServerName  owncloud.ankurkaushal.me
    ServerAlias owncloud.ankurkaushal.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/owncloud/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the most recent error.log

```
[Sun Aug 25 02:25:30 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 25 02:26:57 2013] [error] [client 24.212.255.66] File does not exist: /var/www/ankurkaushal/owncloud, referer: http://144.76.93.122/owncloud/
```

Can someone help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: What error is your browser giving you?  Name resolution, failure connecting to server, an HTTP error code?

Comment: I just get this, http://i.imgur.com/qApPMq9.png

Comment: Doesn't look like DNS is resolving for that hostname.  Are you certain you have the DNS configured properly?

Comment: `Host owncloud.ankurkaushal.me not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)` Log in to Namecheap and fix this.

Comment: I just added the A records, shouldn't that be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but you still have DNS caching to deal with. Wait an hour and try again.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I added A records few hours back, does it matter or I have to wait more?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments are suggesting, your DNS does not resolve for this subdomain. A quick look up through dnsstuff.com gives the following:

```
Target  owncloud.ankurkaushal.me  
Timeout Value   1 (default)  
Your Overall Score  Lookup failed
```

If you've added the A record to the zone file at Namecheap, give DNS propagation some time to complete before trying to access this subdomain.